# unexpected string concatenation of literals react.js

Tags: reactjs, concatenation

```
 to={routeName.tutorClassView + '?classId=' + `${_.get(value, '_id')}`}

 to={routeName.tutorClassView + '?classId=' + `${_.get(v, 'id')}` + '&providerId=' + `${_.get(v, 'provider.id')}`}
```

What am i doing wrong here

Comment: what you are gonna do ? what is the value of `routeName.tutorClassView` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use template string literal like this

```
to={`routeName.tutorClassView?classId=${_.get(value, '_id')}`}
```

Comment: Thank u routename was also sent to url but this one worked for me 
to={routeName.tutorClassView`?classId=${_.get(value, '_id')}`}

Answer (score 0):

you can entirely make use of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as below

```
to = `${routeName.tutorClassView}?classId=${_.get(value, "_id")}`;

to = `${routeName.tutorClassView}?classId=${_.get(v, "id")}&providerId=${_.get(
  v,
  "provider.id"
)}`;
```

with curly braces `{}` you are already in JS land so they might not be required when dealing with static and variable values combined like above ..

Comment: Thank you but with only braces it worked for me
to = {`${routeName.tutorClassView}?classId=${_.get(value, "_id")}`};

to = {`${routeName.tutorClassView}?classId=${_.get(v, "id")}&providerId=${_.get(
  v,
  "provider.id"
)}`};